# How to increase the "Number of times revised" passed 1 using workflow

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow

When auditors submit issues; they will fill out the original remediation date

We also have the following fields on the edit form:

"Revised remediation date"
"Number of times revised"

So every time the "Revised remediation date" is chaned; they want "Number of times revised"to increase by 1

I can't seem to figure out how to increase the "Number of times revised" passed 1(I have the field displaying 1 the 1st time it's changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example.

Columns:

- SomeField     (This is your "Revised remediation date" column)
- LastSomeField (same data type as SomeField)
- TimesChange   (numeric column with the number of time the column was changed)

[image]

The workflow is set on run on Created and Changed.

Edit your views to not display the LastSomeField column, or if adding to a Content Type, hide the column.